# Git not tracking a file from a folder - contents.json from .xcassets

Tags: xcode, git, sourcetree, xcasset

I have checked almost all the questions on SO but nothing has worked for me. The issue that I'm unable commit the `Contents.json` file of `.xcassets` whatsoever. Whenever I add new images to `.xcassets` the source control does list the images but not the `Contents.json` file. I'm using a bitbucket repository and not even `SourceTree` is showing this file in the uncommitted changes. Even tried adding all the files via terminal.

```
git add --all
```

Any guess why this is happening and what could possibly be the solution?

**Update:** The `.gitignore` file looks like:

```
ProjectName.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
ProjectName.xcodeproj/xcuserdata
*.xcscheme
xcschememanagement.plist
```

And `.git/info/exclude` looks something like:

```
.DS_Store
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Comment: Would you mind copy & pasting the contents of your repo's ".gitignore" file (if it has one)?

Comment: @G.SylvieDavies there is no `.gitignore` file. The `.git` folder contains `hooks, info, logs, objects, and refs` as subfolders and some other files like `config`, `HEAD` etc.

Comment: ".gitignore" would be in "./.gitignore" (top folder) and not anywhere under ".git/*".

Comment: @adeel `.gitignore` is in your project root

Comment: Most likely the file is being ignored. Use `git check-ignore Contents.json` to find out where the ignore rule comes from.

Comment: @1615903 it prints `Contents.json`.

Answer (score 9):

A lot of time has passed, but it seems I know what it is. I encountered the same problem, and every time I added resources, I had to manually do the following steps: `git add -f`

However, I found out about the command: `git status --ignored`
The command shows all ignored files. After that, I made the `git add -f` command manually, and it worked.

Comment: Thank you, this was so helpful, however needed this with full stop character "git add -f ." then all the ignored "Contents.json" files were added to git.

Comment: @Claytog if this is so then add your comment as an edit to the answer.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, man !!

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have `.xcassets/Contents.json` in one or more of the three ignore files `.gitignore`, `.git/info/excludes` and `~/.gitexclude`.

If that is not the case then try executing below command which will ask Git to start tracking the file again:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

**For your case:**

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged .xcassets/Contents.json
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the contents of `.gitignore`. and `.git/info/exclude` files. I'm not sure where I can fine the `~/.gitexclude` file. Tried the command that you suggested but it threw this error `fatal: Unable to mark file .xcassets/Contents.json`

Comment: run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>` with full path and file name, as `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged /path/to/directory/.xcassets/Contents.json`

Comment: Didn't work either. `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: this error because you are not executing the command - `/path/to/directory/.xcassets/Contents.json` from your project directory

Comment: See my first comment. When I execute this command from the project folder it shows that error.

Comment: I appears that the required path to the directory is relative to the project directory and not the absolute path. However, the problem still remains. The said file is still not in the list of files.

Comment: There is also the `.gitignore_global` file - check it out. In our case it was the reason.

Comment: @RadekWilczak, .gitignore_global , there was the issue